# How can I make a function to make geom_bar() in ggplot2 make a bar plot that lets me inspect colors in a vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a function that lets me quickly inspect the colors stored in a vector. I have this vector for example:

`mycolors <- c("#009900", "#69ce69", "#56B4E9", "#CCCCCC", "#E69F00", "#D55E00")`

I have tried to make a lot of different variations of the function below in order to see which color is in which place in the vector and how it looks:

```
test.palette <- function(cbPalette){
  datatest <- data.frame(
    col = cbPalette,
    x = 1:length(cbPalette),
    val = rep(1, length(cbPalette))
  )
  datatest$col <- levels(datatest$col)[datatest$col]

  print(datatest)

  myplot <- ggplot(data = datatest, mapping = aes(x = x, y = val, fill = col)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5) + 
    # scale_fill_manual(values = rev(datatest$col))
    scale_fill_manual(values = datatest$col)

  print(myplot)
}

mycolors <- c("#009900", "#69ce69", "#56B4E9", "#CCCCCC", "#E69F00", "#D55E00")
test.palette(cbPalette = mycolors)
```

The result I wish to achieve is to have one bar for each color in my vector, where the first bar has the color saved as the first string in the vector mycolors. Underneath each bar I want the index in mycolors that correspond to the color of that bar. I would also like to have a legend with the colors of the bars next to the text strings from mycolors corresponding to each color.

The problem is that colors of the bars does not appear in the same order as the vector and that the colors in the legend does not match the labels next to them.

It might be possible to make an easier way to inspect the colors in a vector, but since I will use ggplot2 to make bar plots that reuse the colors from mycolors and other vectors, I would really appreciate a solution using ggplot2 and geom_bar().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because you need to explicitely define the levels (the order) of the `fill` aesthetics values. Otherwise, R simply sorts them by alphabetic order.

So, your code becomes:

```r
test.palette <- function(cbPalette){
  require(ggplot2)
  datatest <- data.frame(
    col = cbPalette,
    x = 1:length(cbPalette),
    val = rep(1, length(cbPalette))
  )
  datatest$col <- levels(datatest$col)[datatest$col]

  print(datatest)

  myplot <- ggplot(data = datatest, 
                   mapping = aes(x = x, y = val, fill = factor(col, levels = col))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .5) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = datatest$col, name = "My Legend")

  print(myplot)
}

mycolors <- c("#009900", "#69ce69", "#56B4E9", "#CCCCCC", "#E69F00", "#D55E00")
test.palette(cbPalette = mycolors)
```

[image]